# Microsoft PowerBi - CountIF Alternative

Tags: powerbi

G'day,

I have:

- A list of sales order lines
- A list of time required to complete a delivery

A single delivery has an identifier - SALES ORDER #
A single delviery may contain more than one sale order line item

I need to calculate time spent for each delivery.

Example data below.

| SALES ORDER # | Delivery Location |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 135 Barrow Street |
| 1 | 28 Holland Court |
| 1 | 28 Holland Court |
| 2 | 19 Greenwhich Place |
| 3 | 28 Holland Court |

| Delivery Location | Time (Hours) |
| --- | --- |
| 135 Barrow Street | 2 |
| 28 Holland Court | 5 |
| 19 Greenwhich Place | 9 |

I need to display something similar to below:

| SALES ORDER # | Time (Hours) |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 9 |
| 3 | 5 |

In excel i have used COUNTIF to devide the time across the count of SALES ORDER #s and them sum the lines.

Any help is appriciated!

Note: I am fairly new to PowerBi but would concider myself a fairly well versed Excel user.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Time (hours) =
SUMX (
    VALUES ( 'Table'[SALES ORDER #] ),
    SUM ( 'Location'[Time (hours)] )
)
```